# how to show which user connect to Database X in sql-server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

How can I show which user connect to Database X in sql-server 2008 ?

I have many databases in my sql-server 2008 and I need to show only the users that connect and works on database X

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do yopu mean you want to know the ones connected to the database at this moment?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the procedure sp_who - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174313.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Ctrl+Alt+A to open recourse monitor and see which user is connected to your Database X

Answer (score 0):

@gabriel-adams provides a nice script over on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3991934/4244753) similar question. If you're like me and wandered here from a Google Search, this may save you a few clicks.

```
SELECT
    SessionId           = ses.session_id
    ,[Database]    = DB_Name(er.database_id)
    ,[Login]            = ses.login_name
    ,Host               = ses.host_name
    ,StartTime          = er.start_time
    ,ClientAddress      = con.client_net_address
    ,SQLStatement       = st.text
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests er
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(er.sql_handle) st
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions ses ON ses.session_id = er.session_id
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections con ON con.session_id = ses.session_id
WHERE ses.is_user_process = 0x1
AND ses.session_id != @@SPID
ORDER BY
    ses.session_id
```