# How to know how many users are currently connected to the SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssm

I want to know how many users are **currently** connected and accessing something from SQL Server? The current timing is very important in my scenario. I am using `sys.sysprocess`and `sys.dm_exec_sessions` tables from SQL Server.

Comment: this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743227/how-to-show-which-user-connect-to-database-x-in-sql-server-2008) might help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [so_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com/) to get a lot of great information on who is connected. This is a well documented and widely used community script developed by Adam Machanic.